# How to avoid applying style from external style-sheet file?

Tags: css

I have an image tag in my aspx page. But an external sheet is being is referred in that aspx page. In that external stylesheet, there is a style specified for image tag. But I want to avoid that style from being applied. At the same time I don't want to apply any inline/internal style because I don't want any style to be applied to the image tag at all. Is there any way of doing so apart from inline or internal styles?

Comment: You need to negate the applied property. No other way.

Comment: are you using other style properties from the external stylesheet on that page..? can't you just remove the reference of  external css..?

Comment: yeah can't remove reference to external css. And how to negate the applied style?

Comment: @KrishnaTeja : Use !important for that particluar image. Ex: image{width:100px!important;}

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the external style using a more specific path in another stylesheet.

if the css path is:

```
.container img { ... }
```

You can set:

```
.container img.className { overwrite the previous applied styles }
```